# Jenkins 'Cucumber HTML' report in maven based project

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, cucumber-jvm

I created Testing framework using Cucumber in maven and configured the job in Jenkins and everything works as expected.

But I have one concern:-

I want to send cucumber HTML report via email to my team members, for the same I have also written email.java file in which I have attached cucumber HTML report url.

But how can trigger this email class file using maven, so that it can send email after generating cucumber HTML reports?

In a nutshell:- What I want, after generation of cucumber HTML report, that html file should be send to my team members via an email.

Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

That's something that can be achieved with Jenkins [email plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin). It allows to make an attachment in email.

Though, you should consider if that's really what you want to do. Having an email with link to [report on Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Cucumber+Reports+Plugin) is rather confortable too.